# Joomla Component in Git

Tags: git, joomla

I am running a full Joomla installation on my XAMPP environment which is using GIT. But GIT is now full tracking my Joomla installation including the component. I would like to show the component only in Github. I found this one but this is even more work [Joomla Custom Compoment Dev Env : Hot Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315526/joomla-custom-compoment-dev-env-hot-deployment/9318416#9318416)

In short:

- Running Joomla + Component Locally
- Want to show it in GIT like this: 
  https://github.com/dam-man/WorldCup-2014

It has to track only a few folders in this case as the Joomla installation doesn't need to be tracked by GIT. This way I can release a component very quickly by changing a few things and hit the download button in GIT instead of using Phing to make an installable zip file for Joomla.

Is this possible or do I need to track the complete Joomla installation.

Comment: Check out [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, couldyou point me a bit as I have added the submodule now I think. But the newly created repo is not being filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can create a full ignore list, excluding all elements in your repository that don't belong to your component. GitHub should offer you this option while creating a new repository.
   It's a bit ugly to see, but it's effective.
2. Symlink you files from your repository to your Joomla site. This is much more elegant, but it's a little more complicated.
   For example you have this repo structure:

   extension
     ... backend
     ... frontend

You will have to symlink the entire folder `backend` to `joomla_path/administrator/com_your_component` and the `frontend` one to `joomla_path/com_your_component`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need :) The only thing is that I have two repos now, but that is not a problem for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created something similar to your requirement. https://github.com/gunjanpatel/joomla-webdev-sample-repo may be this will help you or someone else and save time.